# Dropdownlist Id is not visible in ascx.cs.I'm working on ascx page that contains grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on ascx page that contains grid view which display result only on filtering developed by previous coder.I can see the code in ascx souce but grid is not visible in design.Also there is a ddl in this grid in edititemtemplate.If i try to use this in ascx.cs it is not visible.

This is source file code in wcJobShuffling.ascx

```
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left: 3px">
   <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="middle">
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAssignTo" runat="server"          OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAssignTo_SelectionIndexChanged">
   </asp:DropDownList>
   </td>
   </tr>
```

In wcJobShuffling.ascx.cs i am unable to get the Id "ddlAssignTo" in intellisense.For example i need to assign datasource ie... ddlAssignTo.DataSource=objds.Tables[0].

wcJobShuffling.ascx.cs

```
  protected void ddlAssignTo_SelectionIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

        string strRole;
        DataSet dsEmpName;
        if (Session["RoleName"].ToString() == "SAO")
        {
            strRole = "SAO";
            ClsEmployeeDetails objClsEmployeeDetails = new ClsEmployeeDetails();
            dsEmpName = objClsEmployeeDetails.GetAllEmployeesbyRoleName(strRole);
            navigationJobs.Visible = true;
            ddlAssi

        }
      }
```

Comment: can you please paste your code ? Its not possible for anyone to figure out whats the problem

Comment: Is ddlAssignTo public?

Comment: actually ddlAssignTo is an id of control dropdownlist which is in source view...How can we know it is of type public?

Comment: The scope of the control should be defined in the wcJobShuffling.ascx.designer.cs file.

Comment: But in my project i cannot find ascx.designer.cs file.How can i find this?